# Pyspark: Using map function instead of collect for iterating RDDs

Tags: python-2.7, pyspark, rdd

In PySpark ,I've two RDD's which are structured as (key,list of list) :

```
input_rdd.take(2) 
[(u'100',
  [[u'36003165800', u'70309879', u'1']]),
 (u'200',
  [[u'5196352600', u'194837393', u'99']]) ]   

output_rdd.take(2)
[(u'100', 
   [[u'875000', u'5959', u'1']]),
 (u'300', [[u'16107000', u'12428', u'1']])]
```

Now i want a resultant RDD (as shown below) which is grouping the two RDD's based on keys and giving output as tuple in the order (keys,( ,)).Incase the key was not present in anyone of the input or output then the list of that rdd remains empty.

```
[(u'100',
 ([[[u'36003165800', u'70309879', u'1']]],
 [[[u'875000', u'5959', u'1']]]),
 (u'200',
 ([[[u'5196352600', u'194837393', u'99']]],
  [])),
 (u'300',([],[[[u'16107000', u'12428', u'1']]])
 ]
```

For obtaining the resultant RDD i'm using the below piece of code using

```
 resultant=sc.parallelize(x, tuple(map(list, y))) for x,y in sorted(list(input_rdd.groupWith(output_rdd).collect()))
```

Is there a way i can remove .collect() and instead use .map() with groupWith function to obtain the same resultant RDD in Pyspark?

Comment: gives empty rdd

Answer (score 0):

A full outer join gives:

```
input_rdd.fullOuterJoin(output_rdd).collect()
# [(u'200', ([[u'5196352600', u'194837393', u'99']], None)), 
#  (u'300', (None, [[u'16107000', u'12428', u'1']])), 
#  (u'100', ([[u'36003165800', u'70309879', u'1']], [[u'875000', u'5959', u'1']]))]
```

To replace `None` with `[]`:

```
input_rdd.fullOuterJoin(output_rdd).map(lambda x: (x[0], tuple(i if i is not None else [] for i in x[1]))).collect()

# [(u'200', ([[u'5196352600', u'194837393', u'99']], [])), 
#  (u'300', ([], [[u'16107000', u'12428', u'1']])), 
#  (u'100', ([[u'36003165800', u'70309879', u'1']], [[u'875000', u'5959', u'1']]))]
```